# FQL - getting photo record given pid

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to do something very simple - getting a 'photo' record for a given pid. I am using:

```
SELECT pid,aid,owner,src_small,src_small_height,src_small_width,src,src_height,src_width,src_big,src_big_width,src_big_height,link,caption,created,modified,object_id FROM photo WHERE pid = '2622555765931507709'
```

I always get an empty result with no error. What am I doing wrong? I have tried the exact same request but with a 'WHERE aid = '' and that works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result from the GraphAPI: [GraphAPI](https://graph.facebook.com/2622555765931507709)

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "QueryParseException",
      "message": "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 2622555765931507709"
   }
}
```

Something must go wrong with your photo id. Can you give me the album id? Are you sure that the photo you are looking for exists

Comment: I realized after all that I was using the wrong id :(. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem, I didn't help much:)